# paste command leaves empty rows

Tags: awk, paste, cut

Hi I was trying to paste multiple files (each with a single column but different number of rows) together.

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt paste3.txt ... paste100 > out.txt
```

input file 1:

```
A
B
C
```

input file 2:

```
D
E
```

input file 3:

```
F
G
H
I
J
```

output:

```
A   D   F
B   E   G
C       H
        I
        J
```

When I cut column 2 (cut -f2) from out.txt file , it gives column 2 with 3 empty rows (probably because column has 5 rows so to match to column 3, it created 2 extra empty rows). Same goes for column 1 (less out.txt | cut -f1) which gives 2 empty rows. Any ideas why does it show the empty rows?

less out.txt | cut -f1

```
A
B
C
empty cell
empty cell
```

less out.txt | cut -f2

```
D
E
empty cell
empty cell
empty cell
```

I was expecting to see-

column 1

```
A
B
C
```

column 2

```
D
E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the rows are empty, some of them just don't have all of the fields populated but they do still have the field separators (tabs) that paste output. `cut` has no way of knowing that you don't want the empty fields printed.

Try:

```
awk -v f=1 -F'\t' '$f!=""{print $f}' file
awk -v f=2 -F'\t' '$f!=""{print $f}' file
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `awk` to do the replacement of blank fields with the *empty cell* value. Here I have used '|' as a delimiter to make the replacement operation flawless. The delimiter can again be converted to tabs or spaces if wanted with `tr -s '|' '\t'`.

```
$ paste -d '|' {a,b,c}.txt|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print ($1=="" ? "empty cell" : $1), ($2=="" ? "empty cell" : $2), ($3=="" ? "empty cell" : $3)}'
```

Output with pipe delimited.

> A|D|F 
>   B|E|G 
>   C|empty cell|H 
>   empty cell|empty cell|I 
>   empty cell|empty cell|J

Output with tab delimited.

```
A   D   F
B   E   G
C   empty cell  H
empty cell  empty cell  I
empty cell  empty cell  J
```